# Android IDE for Ubuntu

Tags: android, ide

Are there any other IDEs other then eclipse for Ubuntu which can be used for Android Development

Answer (score 0):

Android application development IDE's for Ubuntu:

- [Android studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)
- [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/install/)
- [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads/)

Comment: Android studio is good.. But is there any way to get that application shortcut in gnome desktop.. kindly tell me..